# Creation of google map url in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I need to create a map url as below
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=28.6139,77.2090

I am using react-native-maps, url should be created based on the lattitude and longitude

Can any one help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explain your question with more details. As far as I understand you want to get the latitude and longitude from `react-native-maps` and create a google maps url to redirect?

If is that so;

```
export const createNavigationURL = (startLat, startLng, lat, lng) => {
  const scheme = Platform.select({
    ios: `maps:${startLat}?q=`,
    android: `geo:${startLng}?q=`,
  });
  const latLng = `${lat},${lng}`;
  const label = "Custom Label";
  const url = Platform.select({
    ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
    android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`,
  });
  return url;
};
```

You can use this helper function to make it